# Tooltip onclick to hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I hide the tooltip after I click the dropdown menu? Here is the script

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
        placement : 'bottom'
      });  
    });
  </script>
```

This is the html

```
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li class="dropdown" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Main Link">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: *"How do I hide the tooltip after I click?"* Click where exactly?

Comment: <li class="dropdown" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Main Link">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i></a>

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but you can try using this, Change this:

```
<li class="dropdown" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Main Link">
```

with:

```
<li id="tooltip" class="dropdown" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Main Link">
```

and JS:

```
$(".dropdown-menu li").click(function() {
    $('#tooltip').tooltip('hide');
});
```